# coremedia.playerserver error: Category cvcl is not supported

Tags: ios, xamarin, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I'm using AVFoundation to handle audio in my iOS app.
On the application startup the audio session is SoloAmbient with Default category by default.

Then I want to switch to Ambient category (Xamarin syntax):

```
NSError error; 
var audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance(); 
audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSession.CategoryAmbient, out error);
```

The category is set without any errors within the app by in the device log I see the following:

> May  1 05:54:59 iPod-touch mediaserverd[36] : 05:54:59.503
>   EXCEPTION:  ERROR:     [com.apple.coremedia.playerserver] >va> 3121:
>   kVirtualAudioObjectCategoryNotSupportedError: "Category cvcl is not
>   supported."

What could be reason, how can it affect the app?
I'm not referring to this particular situation, I'm getting those errors when app is working a lot, mostly when trying to switch between different categories and modes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this issue has been resolved by, allow app to use device microphone to record sound from OS settings. And sound file is played, after recording..:)

Please try this way.
You can also check for permission is granted or not, else prompt message.

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
            // Microphone enabled code
        }
        else {
            // Microphone disabled code
        }
    }];